different integral signs for \int versus \iint
I need to use both single and multiple integral signs, but latex produces slanted single integral signs and up-right multiple integral signs.  Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
$
\int \iint \iiint 
$

$
\oint \oiint  \oiint
$

\end{document}

Question:  How can I get latex to produce up-right single integrals sign for both \int and \oint?   Many thanks!

That's documented behaviour of wasysym. You might want to load it with the option integrals.

@campa:  I just tried \usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym} and (a) all the multiple integrals are now slanted and spreaded out (and looked ugly), which is NOT what I want, (b) $\oiint$ does not produce any symbol.

if you do not load wasysm the first four of your examples all use the same, slanted, style,  if you really need oiint  you could look to get it a different way

@campa: My bad --- \usepackage[integrals] does give exactly what I want.   Can you explain briefly what you meant by "documented behaviour"?  And what's the `side effect' of the "integrals" option?

why is this tagged latex3

@carlisle:  I thought all questions about latex should be tagged with that?  Forgive my ignorance :-(

You are using a mixture of fonts here, you could not load wasysym and use the standard fonts with slanted integrals (but they do not have a circled double integral by default) or use a larger font set such as stix which has all these symbols in a matching style (although stix fonts, designed to complement Times Roman, are a lot heavier than the cm fonts)
(Your example had circled double integral twice, I changed the last one to circled triple integral here)

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
$
\int \iint \iiint 
$

$
\oint \oiint  \oiiint
$

\end{document}


\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[upint]{stix2}

\begin{document}
$
\int \iint \iiint 
$

$
\oint \oiint  \oiiint
$

\end{document}

As you see, stix has all six integrals in upright and slanted styles.

If you want to take all integrals from wasysym you want to use the integrals option.
For mysterious reasons, without the option only the multiple integrals are affected.
\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage[integrals]{wasysym}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\mathindent}{\parindent}}

\begin{document}

$\int \iint \iiint$

$\oint \oiint  \oiint$

\begin{gather*}
\int \iint \iiint \\
\oint \oiint  \oiint
\end{gather*}

\end{document}

The fleqn option and the setting of \mathindent are used just to get a smaller picture.

